# How do I Mock an interface property that is an interface

Tags: c#, interface, mocking, moq

```
public interface IFoo
{
    IFoo2 Foo2 { get; }
}

public interface IFoo2
{
    string FooMethod();
}
```

Say I have the 2 interfaces above.  I am trying to mock the interface that is set up as a property on the other interface.  Is this possible?

```
Mock<IFoo> mockFoo = new Mock<IFoo>();
Mock<IFoo2> mockFoo2 = new Mock<IFoo2>();

mockfoo.SetupGet<IFoo2>(x => x.Foo2).Returns(mockFoo2);
```

Complains that it cant convert a `IFoo2` to `Moq.Mock<IFoo2>`:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Moq.Mock<IFoo2>' to 'IFoo2'

Comment: updated, I am using Moq.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reference the `Object` property to access the mocked instance.

```
Mock<IFoo> mockFoo = new Mock<IFoo>();
Mock<IFoo2> mockFoo2 = new Mock<IFoo2>();

mockFoo.SetupGet(x => x.Foo2).Returns(mockFoo2.Object);
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it did not work was that you forgot `.Object` on the inner mock instance when you set up the outer mock (see Grant Winney's answer).

But note that you do not *have to* mention the inner mock (your `mockFoo2`) explicitly. You can just pass the outer mock a "long" expression tree with an extra period `.` ("auto-mocking hierarchies (also known as [recursive mocks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart))"). Like this:

```
Mock<IFoo> mockFoo = new Mock<IFoo>();
mockFoo.Setup(x => x.Foo2.FooMethod()).Returns("your string");

// use 'mockFoo.Object' for your test
```